# Concatenar varios registros de un solo campo

Tags: postgresql

Estoy intentando concatenar varios registros que hay dentro de un campo, lo que busco obtener es lo siguiente

```
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41y73pMiZTL.jpg,https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51+Rsl33kXL.jpg,https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51qcsYkdBPL.jpg,
```

lo que he intentado es

```
 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/' ||'' ||t1.imagescsv|| ',' 
                                 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/' ||'' ||t1.imagescsv|| ','
                                 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/' ||'' ||t1.imagescsv|| ','
                                 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/' ||'' ||t1.imagescsv|| ','
                                 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/' ||'' ||t1.imagescsv|| ','
                                 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/' ||'' ||t1.imagescsv|| ','
                                  'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/' ||'' ||t1.imagescsv|| ','
                                     as imagen_completo,
```

y tambien esto

```
concat('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/',string_agg(T1.imagescsv, ','))
```

y lo que he conseguido hasta el momento , es que pone los datos de la siguiente manera es decir para algunos funciona , pero no para todos.,
**En la parte donde esta señalado es como debería quedar para todos**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en el campo imagecsv de origen es la siguiente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De que otra manera puedo lograr esto ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No conozco tu modelo de datos, por lo que es dificil poder dar una respuesta.

Lo que inferí de tu pregunta es que quieres agrupar registros (utilizando algún criterio) y concatenar la columna imagescsv de los registros de cada grupo (pero además a cada imagencsv hay que concatenarle al principio la url: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/').

En lugar de esto:

```
concat('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/',string_agg(T1.imagescsv, ','))
```

Creo que lo que quieres es:

```
string_agg('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/' || T1.imagescsv, ',')
```

**ACTUALIZADA**

Según entiendo, a partir de tu aclaración, en la columna imagescsv (en cada registro) puede haber varios nombre de archivo jpg. En ese caso estas queries te servirán (asumo que en la columna imagescsv los nombres de archivo jpg están separados por una coma):

Basicamente lo que hacen las queries es separar los nombres de archivo jpg (utilizando como delimitador la coma), y luego los vuelven a concatenar (pero previamente les concatenan la url al princpio de cada uno).

```
WITH T1split AS (SELECT imagescsv, unnest(string_to_array(imagescsv, ',')) AS imagescsv_split
                 FROM T1)
                        
                        
SELECT string_agg('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/' || imagescsv_split, ',')
FROM T1split
GROUP BY imagescsv;
```

ó

```
SELECT string_agg('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/' || imagescsv_split, ',')
FROM (
      SELECT imagescsv, regexp_split_to_table(imagescsv, ',') AS imagescsv_split
      FROM T1) AS T1split
GROUP BY imagescsv;
```

Lo ideal sería agrupar utilizando la primary key o alguna columna cuyos valores sean únicos (y no imagescsv), porque si dos filas tienen la misma cadena en imagescsv entonces las va a agrupar como una sola. Pero como no conozco la tabla agrupé utilizando la única columan que conozco.

**Otra forma de resolverlo:**

Primero concateno una coma al inicio de la cadena. Luego remplazo todas las comas por ',url' y luego quito la primer coma.

```
SELECT substring(replace(',' || imagescsv, ',', ',https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/') from 2)
FROM T1;
```

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo y leer, quizas no formule bien la pregunta, lo que indicas con 
string_agg('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/' || T1.imagescsv, ',') lo que hace es que concatena la ulr al principio, y dentro del campo hay varios ficheros que terminan con jpg y necesito es que cada jpg tenga su ulr pero dentro del mismo campo

Comment: Por eso es importante conocer el modelo de datos (la estructura de la tabla en este caso y contar con datos de ejemplo). Según entiendo en cada registro en la columna  imagescsv tines varias nombre de archivo que terminan con jpg. Podrías compartir un ejemplo de algunos registros, porque no me queda claro como sería (por ejemplo que separa un nombre de otro: un espacio, una coma, nada, etc).

Comment: Yo usé la función de agregación `string_agg()` porque pense que en cada registro había un nombre de archivo jpg, y querías agrupar varios registros utilizando `GROUP BY`; además de que tu la utilizaste en tu pregunta.

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta en función de lo que interpreté de tu aclaración. Asumí que en la columna imagescsv los nombre de archivo jpg están separados por coma.

Comment: No había visto bien la imagen con los datos originales de la columna imagecsv que compartiste. Igualmente no es aconsejable compartir imágenes siempre y cuando sea posible, porque no se aprecian muy bien y no se puede utilizar el contenido para probar.

Comment: Exacto, le diste donde era, mil gracias no sabes lo agradecido que estoy!!

Comment: De nada @SoftQuick! Me alegra haberte ayudado.